# Excel change strings in formulas while copying

Tags: excel

I have a cell number as a string ("A1") in a formula, and this needs to be changed relatively while copying, like it does automatically to normal cell references. so I don't have to visit 400 cells and change them all by hand.
Any way I can manage this? Thanks for the help.

Formula I am using in 400 cells:

```
    =IF(IDENTIC($M$10;"Entries are correct.");IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A1";$N$5));"S1";IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A1";$N$6));"S2";IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A1";$N$7));"S3";IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A";$N$8));"S4";IF(ISNUMBER(FINDEN("A1";$N$9));"S5";"")))));"")
```

I don't want to change every single cell as text in all 400 cells, it should change relatively as normal cell references do.

Comment: Give us an example to work with.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Just did.

Comment: Try using `CELL("address";A1)` to get cell references as strings, this should auto-update if you copy and paste the formula.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a cell reference as a string in Excel you can use the [`CELL` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf):

```
=CELL("address";A1)
```

Since the second parameter to the function is an *actual* cell reference, if you copy and paste this formula it will auto-update accordingly.

Bear in mind this will return a string containing an absolute address so it will return `"$A$1"`, not `"A1"`.

Answer (score 0):

CELL(...) will work.

More generally, you can also build the formula as strings using concatenations. This can be useful when you have a list of stuff and you would like to have formulas that refer to those names. Or in your case it would also work.

**Building the formula as string with concats & then search & replace**

First I build up as much as I can the formula so that the general structure is already formed (only the reference you'll want to change will not be final):

Using your case as an example:

[image]

Then, I wrap that nearly-formed formula into a CONCATENATE(). I then arrange things to have a references that I will point to within that CONCAT() that will auto-increment to the text I actually want to include in my formula. Something like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("IF(FIND(""",A1,"""$A$4),TRUE, FALSE)")
```

The ,A1, refers to the actual cell, so that cell's content is what will be included in my formula. You can then increment this all the way to build the proper formula for each cell (the 400 ones in your case). You need the triple """ because you want to actually include A1, B1 etc... are text references, not cells.

[image]

Then, all you need to do is selected all those formulas, copy them & make sure to choose past as values, say the line under (to keep you concatenate intact so you can edit it later if needed). Then with that pasted line all selected, you use a find & replace to add an "=" sign to the beginning of formulas. Better be too specific on the find & replace, so find "IF(F" and replace by "=IF(F" or similar. Then magic happens:

[image]

You can see that A1, C1, D1 have returned TRUE while the rest are #VALUE! because the find method has failed to find the string.